# Double tap on ios safari position:absolute element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I have an element with

```
position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0
```

When I scroll a few times so safari's bottom bar is hidden, I have to double tap on this element to get it to work. When I tap for the first time, safari's bottom bar shows up. When I tap for the second time, click event finally triggers.
How can I make it work without tapping twice? Thanks!

Comment: I thied this - http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/solving-the-double-tap-issue-on-ios-devices/ but no luck :(

Comment: This is native browser behavior that you'll have to work around. Either reposition the bottom bar, or live with it ;)